# Aframe custom component, custom property in schema results in error

Tags: javascript, aframe, archilogic

I want to have two custom properties in my schema, that have a fallback value if they are not defined, or if their value is below 0.0

this is the schema:

```
schema: {
  url: { type: 'string'},
  key: { type: 'string'},
  intensity: {
    // default is -100 to trigger fallback
    default: -100, 
    parse: function (value) { 
      if (value >= 0.0) { 
        return value 
      } 
      return -100
    } 
  }
}
```

The property that is giving me issues is the intensity property.
If it is **defined** in the a-entity

`<a-entity io3d-data3d="key: mykey; lightMapIntensity: 1.0" shadow="receive: true"></a-entity>`

the value is properly used by the component, but when I open the a-frame 3d editor and click on the entity - I get this error:

[image: A-frame error]

this does **not** happen, if the attributes are not set in `a-entity`.

Am I doing something wrong when using custom properties? 
Is there a way to define optional properties, that have undefined or null as a default value?

Custom Property Type:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/core/component.html#custom-property-type

Comment: what value are You trying to pass as the intensity ?

Comment: <a-entity io3d-data3d="key: mykey; lightMapIntensity: 1.0" shadow="receive: true"></a-entity>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The a-frame inspector tries to round up the values using the `toFixed(decimalPlaces)` function.

The passed values in the component are strings, and as far as i know, `toFixed()` does not work with strings, at least not in my experiments, nor in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

A simple solution is to return a parsed value:

```
if (value >= 0.0) {
  return parseFloat(value);
}
```

Although when comparing strings with floats, it is doing some additional parsing, You may want to parse the value before the check:

```
value = parseFloat(value);
if (value >= 0.0) {
  return value);    
}
```

Comment: thank you! for some reason i did not think that far and it took me a while longer :)

Comment: @MadlainaKalunder no problem :) I got so weided out that it did not work only when accessing the entity from the inspector, that i needed to dig in a bit :) glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I noticed that my schema tried to parse my property as string.
I guess this is the fallback, if you don't define a type?

```
lightMapIntensity: {
  // default is -100 to trigger fallback to value specified in data3d file
  type:'float',
  default:-100.0,
  parse: function (value) {
    if (parseFloat(value) >= 0.0) {
      return parseFloat(value)
    }
    return -100.0 // = fallback to value from data3d file
  }
}
```

At least I don't have the error anymore.

Maybe someone has a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, the parse function's entire purpose is to parse strings.